# ShareKit PKMultipartInputStream linker error

Tags: objective-c, linker-errors, sharekit

Recently I've updated ShareKit in my app via the git submodule method.
However, now it won't build anymore. I've gone through the installation Wiki again, seeing if I've missed any frameworks to include or something, but I can't find any I've missed.
Besides this, I've also changed the setting "Build active architecture only" to no, so it will always build all architectures. But to no avai.l

The error I'm getting is the following:
`Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PKMultipartInputStream", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libOAuth.a(NSMutableURLRequest+Parameters.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7`

Strange thing is, I also included ShareKit in another project and there it didn't give any errors. So I know I must be doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what. Do you guys have any hints of where to look? Or has one of you encountered the same error?

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by adding PKMultipartInputStream.m to the Compiled Sources in OAuth build settings inside ShareKit subproject

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to add PKMultipartInputStream target to Target Dependencies and libPKMultipartInputStream to Link Binary With Libraries in your project.
It is better than making changes to external project.